# Python setdefault function in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to do something similar in Clojure:

# Increase the count of a feature/category pair

```
  def incf(self,f,cat):    
    self.fc.setdefault(f,{})    
    self.fc[f].setdefault(cat,0)    
    self.fc[f][cat]+=1
```

Does anybody have idea?

Answer (score 8):

I think a close parallel is [`fnil`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fnil) which takes a function and some default argument value(s), then returns a function that will use the default value if called with nil argument(s):

```
(defn incf [fc f cat]
  (update-in fc [f cat] (fnil inc 0)))

(incf {} :feature-foo :category-bar)
=> {:feature-foo {:category-bar 1}}
```

Here we use `update-in` to update a nested value in the input map, and use `fnil` to set the default value zero to be incremented if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I really need to remember `fnil` more often. I write `(update … #(if % (f %) :something))` so often, it's embarrassing.

Answer (score 2):

First, you cannot mutate a hash map in Clojure, so there is no exact counterpart for  `setdefault`.

However, if you want to update a nested map increasing the given value (or set to 1, if it is null), you can leverage the fact that `clojure.core/get` can accept an optional third argument which is the default value (and also, an `assoc` on `nil` creates a map):

```
(defn incf [m cat f]
  (let [val (get-in m [cat f] 0)]
    (assoc-in m [cat f] (inc val))))

(incf {:my-cat {:a 1}} :my-cat :a) ; returns {:my-cat {:a 2}}
(incf {:my-cat {}} :my-cat :a)     ; returns {:my-cat {:a 1}}
(incf {} :my-cat :a)               ; returns {:my-cat {:a 1}}
```